# How to Changing image size during mouse hover in loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I apply Javascript on Below code it effect on only first image only first image size is change even my mouse is hovering over any image

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach( $gigs as $gig )
        <div class=" col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 gigbox">
            <div class="panel panel-default" style="height: 285px">
                <img src="{{URL::asset($gig->image)}}" id="img" width="100%" onmouseover="changesize()" height="160"  alt="">
                <ul class="skillUl">
                    <li class="gigtitle" style="list-style: none"><a  href="{{route('gig',['gig_id'=>$gig->id, 'gig_title'=>$gig->gigtitle])}}"> I will  {{$gig->gigtitle}}</a></li>
                    <a class="startingFrom" href="{{route('gig',['gig_id'=>$gig->id, 'gig_title'=>$gig->gigtitle])}}">Starting From <Span class="price"> Rs {{$gig->price}}</Span></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

javaScript Code is here

```
<script>
    function changesize() {
        document.getElementById("img").style.width = "130px";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: an ID must be unique...

use class or set it with css img:hover ... transform scale

Comment: Can you please write code for me? I am new in web

Comment: put the css sample at the end of your css ...

Comment: then delete this `onmouseover="changesize()`

Answer (score 0):

css sample

```
img { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }
img:hover { transform: scale(1.1); }
```

Comment: Basically, i want to change size to small by javascript and show some additional information there on hover. Just like Fiverr.com when we mouse over on any gig its change picture size and show additional information like user name and rating information above image on hover

Comment: Changing size to small = `transform: scale(0.5)`

You have not asked for display additional informations on hover...

Please build a fiddle with all informations ...

Answer (score 0):

You are using a loop to create multiple elements with `id="img"`. `id`s are supposed to be unique on any given page. You should instead use `class="img"` and use the `getElementsByClassName()` method:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("img").style.width = "130px";
```

You also should consider Frank Wisniewski's suggestion to use CSS. You can probably achieve most or all of what you've described without javascript.